# Uniform distributions in HMMs

Tags: r, hidden-markov-models

it seems I am making a mistake in my assumptions. I want to apply a HMM to a sequence of discrete states. It is an explorative analysis in which I have no clue about the putative hidden states that might (or might not) be underlying the observed sequences.

**Version 1)**

Well. Therefore, I defined a small number of states and defined uniform transition and emission probabilities:

```
NUM.STATES = 6

states <- c() # we will create k dummy states
for (i in 1:NUM.STATES) {
  states <- c(states, paste0("State_", i))
}
start.probs <- rep(1.0 / NUM.STATES, NUM.STATES) # we assume equal probability for all states
trans.probs <- matrix(rep(start.probs, NUM.STATES), ncol=NUM.STATES, nrow=NUM.STATES)
rownames(trans.probs) <- colnames(trans.probs) <- states

symbols <- observations.alphabet
num.symbols <- length(symbols)
tmp.probs <- rep(1.0 / num.symbols, num.symbols) 
emit.probs <- matrix(rep(tmp.probs, NUM.STATES), ncol=num.symbols, nrow=NUM.STATES)
rownames(emit.probs) <- states
colnames(emit.probs) <- symbols
emit.probs <- t(emit.probs)
```

The initial probabilities trivially look as following:

```
> trans.probs
          State_1   State_2   State_3   State_4   State_5   State_6
State_1 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
State_2 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
State_3 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
State_4 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
State_5 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
State_6 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667

> head(emit.probs)
                 State_1    State_2    State_3    State_4    State_5    State_6
A  0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158
B  0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158
C  0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158
D  0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158
E  0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158
F  0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158 0.05263158
```

When I fit a HMM with these initial parameters to a sequence of observations, the transition matrix does not change at all.

```
require(hmm.discnp)
tmp.hmm <- hmm(y=observation, yval=observations.alphabet, 
+                                    par0=par0, verbose=T)

      Initial set-up completed ...

Repeating ...

EM step 1:
     Log-likelihood: -648.1533
     Percent decrease in log-likelihood: 20.53143
     Root-SS of change in coef.: 0.630401
     Max. abs. change in coef.: 0.127874
EM step 2:
     Log-likelihood: -648.1533
     Percent decrease in log-likelihood: 0
     Root-SS of change in coef.: 0
     Max. abs. change in coef.: 0

> tmp.hmm$tpm
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
[2,] 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
[3,] 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
[4,] 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
[5,] 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
[6,] 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
```

One can see, that the learning stops after only two iterations! I thought this was evidence that there is no real information in the observed sequence.

**Version 2)**

However, if I use a random initialization of trans.probs and emit.probs it seems to give more reasonable results.

```
tmp.hmm <- hmm(y=observation, yval=observations.alphabet, 
                                   K=NUM.STATES, verbose=T, rand.start=list(tpm=T,Rho=T))

 Initial set-up completed ...
```

Repeating ...

```
EM step 1:
     Log-likelihood: -645.833
     Percent decrease in log-likelihood: 23.1746
     Root-SS of change in coef.: 0.761316
     Max. abs. change in coef.: 0.306738
EM step 2:
     Log-likelihood: -643.9232
     Percent decrease in log-likelihood: 0.295714
     Root-SS of change in coef.: 0.075387
     Max. abs. change in coef.: 0.032037

(...)

EM step 63:
     Log-likelihood: -520.5877
     Percent decrease in log-likelihood: 9.8e-05
     Root-SS of change in coef.: 0.000836
     Max. abs. change in coef.: 0.000365
```

Obviously, the learning now seems to work. And the resulting transition matrix also looks much more interesting:

```
> tmp.hmm$tpm
             [,1]          [,2]         [,3]          [,4]         [,5]         [,6]
[1,] 3.821969e-35  6.218981e-72 9.804360e-01  1.956405e-02 9.371930e-79 3.591732e-38
[2,] 3.167994e-01  6.832006e-01 1.395910e-41  5.558022e-63 3.729498e-17 1.879235e-08
[3,] 2.922663e-01  5.705791e-02 1.918361e-01  2.948879e-02 2.427380e-10 4.293510e-01
[4,] 2.872490e-12 2.558908e-151 1.000000e+00  0.000000e+00 1.532313e-75 7.253783e-75
[5,] 1.866111e-32  4.066253e-01 2.264881e-51 3.583309e-101 5.930935e-01 2.811617e-04
[6,] 3.272425e-31  5.905480e-01 8.061218e-43  6.947626e-02 3.399757e-01 1.029613e-17
```

So, the question is, what is the difference between the two settings and which one to trust!? Where is my flaw in version 1, using uniform ("uninformative") prior probabilities!?

Comment: I had second thoughts on this. May it be a general problem for an EM-algorithm to be started with a uniform prior?